# Explain why accessing the nth element of an array can be done in constant time O(1) compared to O(n) time for a linked-list?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

This is a question on my homework and I can't seem to answer it. Can somebody briefly explain it to me? or just the difference between O(1) and O(n) in a linked list?

Comment: Just think - how can you get n-th element in a linked list.

Comment: @MBo You have go thru the whole list right?

Comment: Not the whole list, but n items, n steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basics first** : all variable internally hold a memory address pointing to the physical starting point where the data of the variable is saved,

Now data type of variable tells how much space will be allocated for the data pointed by the address location stored in variable, int 4, long 8, char 4 ...and so on.

Array variable are simply contiguous allocation of same data-type values and the array variable stores memory location of first data.

**How Arrays provide O(1) fetch for any index** : lets say there is Array variable A with N elements of data-type X, each X data-type occupies m size in memory, so automatically first element will be from memory location of A to A+m, second element will be from A+m to A+m+m = A+m to A+2m, thus the formula:

memory location of n'th index of an Array starting at memory location A occupying m size in memory for each element is

`A+mxn`

ergo its O(1) dip for fetching an index of an array.

**Case with Linked-List** : LLs are not contiguous and each element stores memory location of next element, so you have to traverse through all elements starting from first to reach to n'th element, hence its O(N).

important to note that Array's space-complexity depends upon type of data it stores and can store multiples of same data type only , insertion in array can be at the end only, and time complexity wise its costly to insert an element anywhere else, whereas in LLs space-complexity though depends upon data it stores, but it can store any type of data in each element irrespective of previous element, and time complexity of writing is always O(1), insertion is also simple and easy.

Comment: "all variable internally hold a memory address pointing to the physical starting point where the data of the variable is saved": this is only true for non-primitive types.

Answer (score 2):

In case of an array, the address of the `n`th element can be computed since an array is allocated in **contiguous memory locations**. Thus, an element of an array can be accessed in `O(1)` time.

In the case of a linked list, to access the `n`th element, you will need to traverse the linked list to reach the `n`th element. The complexity in this case is a function of `n` (the number of the element you want to access). Also, the head of the linked list can be accessed in `O(1)` since, the address of the `head` element is known.